# How to get correct cell id and location area code in Android?

Tags: android

I have found so much code that fetches cell-id and location area code and I use the code below to fetch cell-id and location area code.

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
GsmCellLocation cellLocation = (GsmCellLocation) telephonyManager.getCellLocation();

int cid = cellLocation.getCid();
int lac = cellLocation.getLac();
```

The problem is, when I use an airtel-sim card it works fine and give cell-id =4331 and loc =610. But when I use a relience-sim card then it give wrong result cell-id =11541 and loc=18823. How might I resolve this?

Comment: Hi,i use the  code from the url http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/01/convert-celllocation-to-real-location.html to fetch the location and it works fine for airtel but in case relience it does not work . as i know it means that location area code and cell id that i get in case of relience is incorrect. any help?

Comment: There are many application that show correct cell id but my code doesnot work for 3g simcard .

Comment: what is your result with your relience-sim by using `cid = cellLocation.getCid() & 0xffff;`?

Answer (score 1):

Solutions are highlighted in the following thread: [Android: CellID not available on all carriers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808396/android-cellid-not-available-on-all-carriers)

In short you need to mask the number you get from `getCid()` when in 3G network with `0xffff`. Following is a snippet:

```
GsmCellLocation cellLocation = (GsmCellLocation)telm.getCellLocation();

new_cid = cellLocation.getCid() & 0xffff;
new_lac = cellLocation.getLac() & 0xffff;
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Cell IDs and LAC ids are different based on networks, as you have mentioned that you are using two different SIMs of different networks so you will get different cell and lac ids these will not be same. Because cell id of one operator will be different than other network as two different towers are used of different networks and they have assigned accordingly both ids.